# How to check specific word in the url?

Tags: php, url, yii

Suppose I have 3 different urls. All are illustrated below.

```
1. http://www.example.com/foo/bar/index.php?id=1
2. http://www.example.com/bar/foo/index.php?id=1
3. http://www.example.com/foo/contact.php
```

How can I check whether the given url contains foo as of first param. 
I mean how can I get only 1st and 3rd url as `true` and 2nd as `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1: Use parse_url():**

```
$array = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$path = explode('/', $array['path']);
if ($path[1]==='foo')
{
  // Here ya go! :-)
}
```

**Method 2: Use a Regular Expression:**

```
if (preg_match('/^http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/foo\/.*$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
{
  // Here ya go! :-)
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/jZ0pL1/1

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. It worked fine for me... Well I have edited it..

Answer (score 1):

To get your url parameters first we will need to parse your url

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Now we will split it into parts

```
$params = explode('/', $parsedUrl['path']);
```

And finally, to get the first parameter

```
// Getting the second key => value pair
$firstParam = $params[1];
```

To view all parameters

```
print_r($params);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `parse_url()` as below,

```
$arr = parse_url($url);
```

You will get `$arr[2]= 'foo'`, check the requested url using this and that is what you want...

Comment: parse_url() will return an associative array; so `$arr[2]` will be undefined - see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php